# produce live streaming by opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use the code below to produce a live streaming. But there is a Bug said:

> 2017-04-03 22:48:46.836 Python[77177:10332216] !!! BUG: The current
>   event queue and the main event queue are not the same. Events will not
>   be handled correctly. This is probably because _TSGetMainThread was
>   called for the first time off the main thread.

What should I do if I want to stream by write and read a picture?

```
import cv2
import time
import threading

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

count = 0

def produce():
    global count
    while True:
        ret,frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imwrite('./img/'+str(count)+'.png',frame)
        count+=1

def consume():
    global count
    while True:
        if count>0:
            img = cv2.imread('./img/'+str(count_read)+'.png')
            cv2.imshow('a',img)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__=='__main__':
    producer = threading.Thread(target=produce)
    customer = threading.Thread(target=consume)
    producer.start()
    customer.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from defining `count_read` and using `cv2.waitKey(30)` after `cv2.imshow('a',img)`, your code works for me

Have you tried this code using a video file? It usually takes some time to open a webcam, maybe that's the reason for your error?